# pm2 is not working in amazon ec2 with node application

Tags: node.js, nginx, amazon-ec2, npm, pm2

I have node application hosted in amazon ec2.
I used nginx to point it in my domain.
It runs perfectly when i use npm start to run the application.
But when i use pm2, it doesnt work.

[pm2 list command shows that the app is running.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13GDI.png)

But url doesn't work. Even when i again run npm start app gets started that clearly states that the port is free. So pm2 is not actually running anything on that port. But pm2 says app is online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running the wrong file from pm2. As it was express project, so i had to run bin/www

So the following command solve the issue:

```
pm2 start bin/www
```

Answered it here as well:

https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/3252

Thanks